# How a sub container can be larger in width than the main one on top of the html hierarchy

Tags: html, css

I want to style a sub container and make it larger in width than the main one on top of the html structure that force not to exceed the width set for the first container. Which css property should i use for this case? thank you

I tried using max-width property but still not solving the problem

Comment: Have you tried setting fixed `width`?

Answer (score 0):

On the content element use

```
margin-left: calc(A - B);
```

where

```
A = 1/2 width of the container

B = 1/2 width of the content
```

Follow a code Example of 3 nested content of different dimensions.
HTML:

```
<div class="page-wrapper">
      <div class="container container 1">
        <p>Container 1 - width: 600px</p>
        <div class="content content-1">Content 1: width: 800px</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page-wrapper">
      <div class="container container 2">
        <p>Container 2</p>
        <div class="content content-2">Content 2 - width: 160%</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page-wrapper">
      <div class="container container 3">
        <p>Container 3</p>
        <div class="content content-3">Content 3 - width: 1024px</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Code example CSS:

```
.page-wrapper {
  width: 1024px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: solid 1px #000000;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #FF0066;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #666666;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 100vw; /* do not exceed the viewport width; */
}

.content-1 {
  width: 800px;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 400px); /* this center the content */
}
  
.content-2 {
  width: 160%;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 80%); /* this center the content */
}
  
.content-3 {
  width: 1024px;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 512px); /* this center the content */
}
```

The working codepen here: https://codepen.io/Davevvave/pen/XWBepBM

Comment: Thanks for answering my post was helpful, i figure out the right way to style the child section of a parent container right here in this link for anyone who wants more options in this case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48817028/how-to-make-full-width-div-inside-container